# Validating API Calls from Own App

Tags: php, android, api, oauth

My app is an interface to my Php based API, But my problem is that anyone can decompile to code and get my api and use it ..

If i use my SHA as API key then anyone can sniff that from http packet using an proxy server.

I tried a lot about Google auth but i m failing to implement it ..
Please help me .Snippets will be appricated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your requests to be sniffed, use https instead of http. This way, your data is sent encrypted.

You can use letsencrypt.org to get your https set up for free